# VMWare Esxi 8.0 vlan trunking

Tags: vmware, esxi

I'm wanting to trunk ports inside the VMWare esxi 8.0 but I don't know how to trunk multiple ports togheter. Does someone know how to do this?

I made multiple ports groups (VLAN10 till VLAN20) and now I don't know how to trunk them into 1 vSwitch and into a NIC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the VLAN kind of trunk or "link aggregation" (LAG) kind of trunk? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: vlan trunking, I wan't that all my vlans can go trunked to a switch but I don't know how to do it I'm pretty new in this and couldn't find it (I am using a server HP ProLiant DL360p Gen 8)

Answer (score 2):

> I made multiple ports groups (VLAN10 till VLAN20) and now I don't know how to trunk them into 1 vSwitch and into a NIC.

You already did that by creating the port-groups with VLAN IDs. The port-groups are *already* under the same vSwitch, and the vSwitch is already connected to a physical uplink port (all three of them).

Physical ports (NICs) in ESXi vSwitch are always in VLAN trunk mode, and ESXi will automatically use the VLAN ID for 802.1Q tagging ("tagged VLANs" or "trunk port") that your physical switch needs to recognize.

(If you wanted to set up a VM as an inter-VLAN router, you could also switch a port-group to trunk mode by specifying 4095 as its VLAN ID to allow it to receive all VLANs.)

Note that currently you have all three NICs in the same vSwitch. If you want to keep them physically separate, you can go to "Edit settings" on the vSwitch and remove all but one uplink ports, then create new vSwitches (with its own port groups) for each of your physical Ethernet NICs.

Comment: So I don't have to change anything. Now I have to set up the trunk ports on the physical switch?

Comment: Yes. Do you already have a router that'll be forwarding packets between these VLANs?

Comment: No, I have the server as showed (With the VLans) and I have a empty switch and empty router from DrayTek. Whats the best way to install them so the VMWare esxi will forward the vlans?

Comment: maybe if u wanna help me out via a easy to chat with eachother program that would be nice. (Discord or teams)

Comment: ESXi will forward the VLANs themselves but it will not forward *between* VLANs. You'll probably need a "router" VM if you don't have a separate VLAN-capable router.

Comment: I have a router and a switch, but the VLAN's I put in in the VMWare EXSi will they forward to the switch as those VLAN's if I make a trunk port on the switch from VLAN10-VLAN20?

Comment: @WillemYiex -- You should clarify your question enough so an answer can be made, instead of asking for help in chat, so everyone can benefit from your question.  Less now than since you already recieved an answer. The time to ask a clear question was before an answer was submitted.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new into all of this